# Some route of navlinks always remain active

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

By default functionality of Navlink is, it add active to the currently active component. But in my case two of my routes always remain active no matter it is active or not. I checked my routing files and didn't get any idea why it happens. The desired behavior is active class added on only those routes who has currently active.

Here is my routing files

```
<HashRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
                    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
                    <Route path="/forget-password" component={ForgetPassword} />
                    <Route path="/verification-code" component={VerificationCode} />
                    <Route path="/reset-password" component={ResetPassword} />
                    <Route path="/password-reset-success" component={SuccessPassword} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                </Switch>
            </HashRouter>
```

```
<Switch>
                <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Homepage} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/check-in" component={CheckIn} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/deals" component={Deals} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/events" component={Events} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/invoice" component={Invoice} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/notification" component={Notification} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/profile/forget-password" component={ResetPassword} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/redemption"  component={Redemptions} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/restriction-management" component={RestrictionManagement} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/create-event" component={CreateEventForm} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/venue-setting" component={VenueForm} />
                <Route path="/dashboard/new-user" component={NewUserDetail} />
                   </Switch>
```

```
                   <div>
                    <SidebarLink 
                      title="Home" 
                      pagelink="/dashboard" 
                      icon={}
                     />
                     <SidebarLink 
                      title="Profile" 
                      pagelink="/dashboard/profile" 
                      icon={}
                     />
                     <SidebarLink 
                      title="Events" 
                      pagelink="/dashboard/events" 
                      icon={}
                     />
                     <SidebarLink 
                      title="Deals" 
                      pagelink="/dashboard/deals" 
                      icon={}
                     />
                     <SidebarLink 
                      title="Redemption" 
                      pagelink="/dashboard/redemption" 
                      icon={}
                     />
                      <SidebarLink 
                      title="SignOut" 
                      pagelink="/" 
                      icon={}
                      click={this.manageSignOut}
                     />
</div>
```

SidebarLink Component

```
<NavLink to={this.props.pagelink} onClick={this.props.click} className="color-white roboto">
                        <object>
                          {
                              this.props.icon
                          }
                        </object>
                        {this.props.title}
                        </NavLink>
```

Currently, my home component always remains active. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with all relevant code. What does your links code look like? Do the `NavLink` [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) help?

Comment: I added my overall code. I hope this will make you understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to specify the `exact` prop on your  nav links

[NavLink exact](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/exact-bool)

> When true, the active class/style will only be applied if the location
> is matched ***exactly***.

```
<NavLink exact to="/dashboard" />
<NavLink exact to="/dashboard/check-in" />
<NavLink exact to="/dashboard/deals" />
...
```